# What are the mechanical properties of human skeletal muscle?

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology, biophysics, muscles, bio-mechanics

**TL;DR: I need more information on the mechanical properties of human skeletal muscle; if you have such information, please give it to me.**

I'm writing something on how much more effective (or otherwise) [spider silk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_silk) would be as a muscle and/or connective tissue in prosthetics in in comparison to human [skeletal muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_muscle) and [connective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connective_tissue) tissues. As such, I need information on several of the mechanical properties of human skeletal muscle, such as its:

- [fatigue limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_limit); this is particularly irritating to attempt to find info on; looking it up instead gets returns on the entirely unrelated concept of [muscle fatigue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_fatigue), even with [very specific search terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=muscle%20%22fatigue%20limit%20of%22&lr=&safe=images&as_qdr=all&ei=msSaYt72EqiI0PEP38-32Ac&ved=0ahUKEwjeq66T4ZL4AhUoBDQIHd_nDXsQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=muscle%20%22fatigue%20limit%20of%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKsCMgUIIRCrAjIFCCEQqwI6BwgAEEcQsAM6BQghEKABSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUMABWPADYNAEaAFwAHgAgAFuiAGVApIBAzIuMZgBAKABAcgBBMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz).
- [ultimate tensile strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tensile_strength); while I have sources for this, they're inconsistent, giving me values between [0.44 MPa](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25831858/) and [5.3 MPa](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-80448-1) - more than an order of magnitude in difference!
- *tensile and/or compressive* (i.e. end-to-end/lengthwise) [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus); I already have [information on its *transversal* (i.e. perpendicular to a strand) Young's modulus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2814213/#:%7E:text=They%20found%20that%20the%20transversal,3.5%20kPa%20for%20skeletal%20muscles.), which, from what I can tell, is another word for [shear modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus), and therefore is useless for my purposes; after all, good muscles are, AFAIK, supposed to withstand tensile or compressive loads, not the shear ones discussed in that source.
- [elastic modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus); I already have information on it [after 8 days of cell differentiation (45.3 ± 4.0 kPa)](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/ajpcell.00502.2001), or the elastic modulus of the [rectus femoris](https://www.physio-pedia.com/Rectus_Femoris) in [particular (16.67 to 85.31 kPa, depending on pressure applied)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3432131/), but these sources contrast with [one of my sources for skeletal muscle's ultimate tensile strength](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-80448-1), which states that this figure is 36 ± 19 MPa.

I was also able to find [another source on its Young's modulus](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-34719-7), but it doesn't specify the direction the Young's modulus was measured in.

One of the few sources I currently cannot find problems with are [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4822308/), on how much a strand of muscle can elongate before it fails - and that's because I can't find any *other* sources which could contradict it - and [this one](https://books.google.com/books?id=awmprqGqFo4C&pg=PA288#v=onepage&q&f=false), on how much force a longitudinal muscle of a certain [cross-sectional area](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/cross-sectional-area) can contract with: ~30 newtons per square centimetre, or 300 kPa.

There's also the content of and [source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2772832/) of [this Biology Stack Exchange answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/26177/66806) by [WYSIWYG](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/3340/wysiwyg), especially the image displayed:

[image]

...although I'm still trying to figure out which parts of it correspond to which points on a [stress-strain curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93strain_curve).

The unifying factor here, however, is that I don't have enough sources - so few, in fact, that I have no reliable information on the fatigue limit. Please give me more.

Answer (score 1):

Muscle by itself is very weak, all the strength is in the fascia (the tissue around the muscle).

You can see a review [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-80448-1), the muscle itself is negligible strength while the fascia is in the megapascal range.